# writing for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have written a for loop but want to implement it as list comprehension. Followed the usual guides for translating it to a list comprehension, but for some reason the for loop is working but the list comprehension isn't

Below is both my for loop as well as the list comprehension code. Note that "tipos" is a series and "airbnb" a dataframe (though that should not be relevant, I think.

```
for i in range(len(tipos)):
    porcentajes.append(tipos[i]/airbnb.room_type.count()*100)
porcentajes

porcentajes=[porcentajes.append(tipos[i]/airbnb.room_type.count()*100) for i in range(len(tipos))]
porcentajes
```

Using the for loop I get the list I want, but using the list comprehension I get a list full of Nones. I'd be expecting to get the same result as with the for loop. How do I correct the list comprehension?

Comment: use `porcentajes=[tipo / airbnb.room_type.count() * 100 for tipo in tipos]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is actually:

```py
porcentajes=[(tipos[i]/airbnb.room_type.count()*100) for i in range(len(tipos))]
```

(no need to append... you're creating the list by doing the comprehension)

However, I'm not sure why you need the index either, you can likely just loop over the items:

```py
porcentajes=[(t/airbnb.room_type.count()*100) for t in tipos]
```